# calling a code behind member from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an ASPX.CS code:

```
Protected int myprop
```

I would like to call it on a JS assignment :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
...
 data.add(['SomeJSProperty', "<%..myprop from code behind%>"]);
```

I remember doing it with <% %> inline code and it used to view the code behind protected and public members. but it won't work now.

Thanks

Comment: BTW, that's not calling code behind member _from JavaScript_, mind you. That will just render the output of the expression enclosed within `<%= %>` in your JavaScript, and that happens before the JavaScript code block is run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
...
data.add(['SomeJSProperty', "<%= myprop %>"]);
```

More info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi, I tried this but from some reason I am getting this error:The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks

Comment: Add more code to the question then. The info you gave is not enough to solve your problem.

Comment: had to warp the <script> with a runat=server control

Answer (score 0):

In the page_load you can add a input type='hidden' value='my prop' to the page.
and from javascript when document is ready you can simply read that value from the hidden input.